# Ruby || Operator Shortcuts

Tags: ruby

If I have multiple || logical operators I want to chain in Ruby, is there a better way to write it than this:

```
if (((a == 1 || a == 9) || a % 5 == 0) || ... )
```

This just seems extremely repetitive and unclean.

Comment: How many are you talking?  10?  100?

Comment: You can also refactor it into a semantically-meaningful, testable method.

Comment: `[1, 9].include? a` can replace up the first two `||` expressions. There's also `case` statements that can allow you to spread things over multiple lines, etc.

Comment: With the caveat that creating an array for this seems overkill and potentially not immediately obvious.

Answer (score 6):

If all you have is ORs, you don't need parens...

```
(a == 1 || a == 9 || a % 5 == 0)
```

Cleans things up a bit.

Ruby is a fun language.  There may be loads of clever ways you might be able to express the same intent in a way that wasn't so repetitive.  I'd merely caution against favoring brevity over clarity.

The `include?` would be appropriate if you really are just looking for a match within a list.  But don't save a few characters if that's not the most suitable way to express it.

Answer (score 4):

You could put your boolean statements into an array and call #any? on it:

```
if [a == 1, a == 9, a % 5 == 0, ...].any?
```

This might look a bit more readable, but that is certainly dependent on your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

What's the whole statement?

If the body of the conditional is a single statement, for example, you don't need any parentheses:

```
puts 'hi' if a & ~8 == 1 || a % 5 == 0
```

If you're looking for ways to compress mathematical comparisons into something short (like a & ~8 == 1, which is the same as a == 1 || a == 9) then post the whole thing. Some people on SO like that sort of thing. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you've got lots of `||`'s,

let

```
t = [" == 1", " == 9", "%5==0"] or
t = %w[==1  ==9  %5==0] # No spaces other than separators! or
t = "==1  ==9  %5==0".split # Ditto! or
t = "== 1, == 9, %5==0".split(',')
```

Then

```
t.inject (false) {|r, s| r || eval('a'+s) }
```

If you've got lots and lots of `||`'s, you could do something like this before `inject`ing:

```
assignments = [1, 2, 5, ":cat", "dog",...]
other = "%5==0, & 8,...".split(',')
t = assignments.map {|e| "=="+e.to_s} + other
```

Comment: I don't mind downvotes, but I hate downvotes that are given without explanation! I want to know why, so I can improve.  Grrr.